# ggplot2 - how to color code for two variables in a barchart

Tags: r, plot, graph, ggplot2

How can I color code for two different variables?
Currently I alter the opacity:

```
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(1, 0.5), labels=c("net sales", "contribution margin"),name = "Opacity") + # opa
```

So the 2nd bar in the chart is always a little transparent. However what I would really like to have is the 2nd (and following) bar(s) in a group  to be gradually darker / brighter versions of the first one without introducing transparency.

[image: my current graph]

Comment: can you provide some sample data, e.g. using `dput()`

Comment: I still have to learn how to use dput correctly and in this case it is confidental data so I have to make something up....but just imagine a data set with a factor country with 6 levels. For each level of country you have two numeric values, one for net sales and one for contribution margin.

Comment: No problem. Build the data by your own using `runif()` for instance or replace the values and factor labels. This link might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example